# KDB:selecting data “around” time of certain events Part2

Tags: intervals, kdb, q-lang

Follow up to this question...  [KDB:selecting data "around" time of certain events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24389165/kdbselecting-data-around-time-of-certain-events)

Consider a huge table of market data T. I am particularly interested in rows where Status=`SSS.

However, in addition to the rows given by (select from T where Status=`SSS), I also would like to select records that are within a certain short time interval around that event (as opposed to the earlier question, where we selected a fixed number of records surrounding the events).  Note that in some cases, these intervals may overlap. What is an efficient way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [KDB:selecting data "around" time of certain events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24389165/kdbselecting-data-around-time-of-certain-events)

Comment: Not a duplicate, its a follow up to that one.

Comment: as far as I can tell, no answer was accepted for that one, so you might want to simply append to your initial question.

Answer (score 1):

We have an idea here that might help you:

```
q)n:10000000;
q)T:([]time:asc n?1D0;sym:n?3;price:n?100f;status:@[n?`3;-100000?n;:;`SSS])
q)f:{[t;x;d]t where 0<sums sum @[c#0;;+;]'[(-1+c:count t)&t[`time]binr/:x+/:-1 1*d;1 -1]}
q)f[T;exec time from T where status=`SSS;0D00:00:00.01]
time                 sym price     status
-----------------------------------------
0D00:00:01.169838756 2   77.1118   lbh
0D00:00:01.175813376 2   24.94157  emk
0D00:00:01.176316291 2   68.49994  SSS
0D00:00:01.180037856 1   81.54316  hhi
0D00:00:01.183518022 1   0.6516971 hni
0D00:00:01.291926205 2   51.94651  kjf
0D00:00:01.300173997 0   14.67675  SSS
0D00:00:01.309709250 1   82.77418  oji
```

The idea here is to extract out the time of event and use `binr` to find all the time windows that you need:

```
t1  t2  t3  t4  t5  t6  t7  t8  t9  t10
`a  `b  `c  `S  `d  `e  `S  `f  `g  `h
```

Say t3, t5 and t6,t8 meets the time window, we put a marker around them

```
t1  t2  t3  t4  t5  t6  t7  t8  t9  t10
`a  `b  `c  `S  `d  `e  `S  `f  `g  `h
0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   -1  0   0   -1  0
```

`sums sum` will highlight all the records you need:

```
t1  t2  t3  t4  t5  t6  t7  t8  t9  t10
`a  `b  `c  `S  `d  `e  `S  `f  `g  `h
0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
```

then the rest is just straight forward...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method to this is to use [window join, `wj1`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/#wj-wj1-window-join), which allows you to pass in custom windows for each time and perform an aggregation on the data within that window. A simplified explanation of the syntax is:

```
wj[window pairs;common columns;table 1;(table 2;(function;column))]
```

Taking the following tables as an example:

```
q)trade              / simplified trade table
time  sym
---------
09:00 a
09:30 a
10:00 a
q)quote              / simplified quote table
time  sym px
------------------
09:12 a   9.420396
09:29 a   6.416515
10:07 a   8.53406
```

To sums all the `quote` prices within a 20 minute window either side of the `trade` time for each `sym` we use the following method. First create pairs of start and end times for the windows:

```
q)show window:-20 20+\:x`time
08:40 09:10 09:40
09:20 09:50 10:20
```

Where each list has the same length as the `trade` table. Then pass this in to `wj`, alongside the aggregation function `sum` for the prices `px`:

```
q)wj1[window;`sym`time;x;(y;(sum;`px))]
time  sym px
------------------
09:00 a   9.420396
09:30 a   15.83691
10:00 a   8.53406
```

To investigate the values being aggregated in each window we can use the null function `::`:

```
q)wj1[window;`sym`time;x;(y;(::;`px))]
time  sym px
---------------------------
09:00 a   ,9.420396
09:30 a   9.420396 6.416515
10:00 a   ,8.53406
```

It should be noted that `wj1` only considers value inside the window, whereas `wj` considers prevailing values to be part of the window.